# Equivalent of arrayMap on Map type in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have the following table in ClickHouse:

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
(
    id String,
    w Map(UInt32, UInt32)                       
)   
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

I then insert a couple of rows as follows:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('0', {0:1,1:2,2:3} );
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('1', {5:3,10:2,24:1} );
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('2', {4:2,1:3,2:1} );
```

Is there a way to write a Function that will generate, for each row, a map with the same set of keys but the values multiplied by 2 ?

```
id|w                |w * 2            |
--|-----------------|-----------------|
0 |{0=1, 1=2, 2=3}  |{0=2, 1=4, 2=6}  |
2 |{4=2, 1=3, 2=1}  |{4=4, 1=6, 2=2}  |
1 |{5=3, 10=2, 24=1}|{5=6, 10=4, 24=2}|
```

It would be an equivalent of the arrayMap function ([doc](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#array-map)) but on Maps.

EDIT1:

The solution I was able to come with is the following - not sure if it is a good approach.

```
SELECT 
id,
CAST((mapKeys(w), arrayMap(x -> (x * 2) , mapValues(w)) ), 'Map(UInt32, UInt32)') AS map

FROM foo;
```